# Is it possible to create good hummus without a food processor? 

Tags: equipment, middle-eastern-cuisine, hummus

I don't own a food processor and because I don't have much storage in my apartment, I'm not entirely interested in purchasing one right now.

Is it possible to create good hummus without a food processor?

Would a blender be an alright substitute?

Comment: I made it a couple of times with a mortar and pestle. A bit more work than with a food processor, but definitely doable

Comment: I tried it once by mashing the peas with a fork. Would not recommend.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

While you can make a decent hummus with a blender, it will be thinner than the hummus you would make in a food processor (at least thinner than my recipe).

If you have a potato masher or ricer, either would do the job nicely, giving you a texture that is less smooth than you might get with a food processor, but definitely good.  I like the texture when done by hand (think lumpy mashed potatoes) and the flavor, of course, is the same.  You can accomplish the same thing a little easier with a stand or hand mixer.

Keep in mind that hummus has been around a lot longer than the food processor, so if you do it by hand, it will probably be more like "real" hummus.

Comment: It's actually possible to get pretty darn thick hummus with an immersion blender.

Comment: For what it is worth, thickness is not a desirable property in traditional hummus. If you travel in the Middle East, hummus is universally a suave, creamy near-liquid that you could almost drizzle off a spoon, not a thick paste that you could turn upside down in a bowl and have it stick.

Comment: Ricer - good thought!

Answer (score 5):

mortar and pestle works perfectly. Watch out for your fingers, though. When the pestle gets all slippery it is pretty easy to hurt yourself.

In a pinch, I have also used a heavy glass (think mojito) with a thick bottom as a pestle, and a plastic bowl as a mortar. Messy, but when you *must* have hummus messiness is just a detail.

Comment: Bonus points for prioritizing quality, homemade food over having to clean up a mess.

Answer (score 4):

I've always made my hummus in the blender.

Just make sure to put the oil, yogurt and any other liquid ingredients at the bottom (in first) so that they're blended in first, before it gets too dry from the chickpeas.  It'll get pretty thick, but a quick scrape with a spatula will get things moving again.

A recent trick I learned was to use warm chickpeas rather than cold or room temperature... a couple seconds in the microwave and they'll come out much smoother than if they're cold.

And don't forget the tahini!

Answer (score 3):

Slow cooking your own chick peas make them come out very soft and easy to blend, it also makes for much better hummus than the canned variety, before I got an immersion blender, I used a potato masher.

Answer (score 3):

Another idea: push the chick peas through a strainer with wooden spoon.  You can probably get your hummus as smooth as you would with a blender.  Worked for me.

Comment: Welcome to Seasoned Advice! Have you taken the [tour] and visited our [help] yet? It's a good idea to start there to get a better idea of how this site works.

Answer (score 1):

I've used both the strainer method and the potato masher method.  It was a bit labor intensive to get the chick peas through the strainer, but worked OK.  I like the texture I get with the potato masher better.  It's an easy cleanup too; the masher is much easier to wash than the strainer with chickpea remnants is.